# Gaussian Elimination with Scaled Row Pivoting for numerical methods

Tags: matrices, numerical-linear-algebra

I am solving a system first with basic Gaussian Elimination, and then Gaussian Elimination with [scaled row pivoting](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pivot_element#Scaled_pivoting) (used in numerical methods)

Basic Gaussian Elimination on the system $Ax=b$:
$$                                                                                                                                                           
\begin{pmatrix}-1& 1& -4 \\                                                                                                                                                 
                2& 2& 0 \\                                                                                                                                                  
                3& 3& 2 \end{pmatrix}                                                                                                                                       
\begin{pmatrix}x_1\\x_2\\x_3\end{pmatrix} =                                                                                                                                 
\begin{pmatrix}0\\1\\\frac{1}{2}\end{pmatrix}                                                                                                                               
$$

Let $A_i$ denote the $i^\text{th}$ row of matrix $A$ and let $A^{(1)} A^{(2)}\ldots$ denote the matrix after the first, second and so forth elementary row operations. Note that
$A^{0} =A$.

Compute the following elementary row operations:
\begin{align}                                                                                                                                                               
A^{(1)}_2 &= A^{(0)}_2 - (-2)A^{(0)}_1 \\                                                                                                                                   
A^{(1)}_3 &= A^{(0)}_3 - (-3)A^{(0)}_1                                                                                                                                       
\end{align}

This yields:
$$                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                            
\begin{pmatrix}-1& 1& -4 \\                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                  
                0& 4& -8 \\                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                  
                0& 6& -10 \end{pmatrix}                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                      
\begin{pmatrix}x_1\\x_2\\x_3\end{pmatrix} =                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                  
\begin{pmatrix}0\\1\\-1\end{pmatrix}                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                         
$$

Compute:
$$ A^{(2)}_3 = A^{(1)}_3 - \tfrac{3}{2}A^{(1)}_2 $$
This yields:
$$                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                             
\begin{pmatrix}-1& 1& -4\\                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                   
                0& 4& -8\\                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                   
                0& 0& 2\end{pmatrix}                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                         
\begin{pmatrix}x_1\\x_2\\x_3\end{pmatrix}=                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                   
\begin{pmatrix}0\\1\\-1\end{pmatrix}                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                         
$$
Thus we have:
$$ x=\begin{pmatrix}\frac{5}{4}\\                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                             \frac{-3}{4}\\                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                               \frac{-1}{2}\end{pmatrix}$$

Now I will solve the same system with Scaled Row Pivoting. The $i^\text{th}$ element of the list $S$ will denote the maximum element in row $i$ in matrix $A$. $P$ will denote the order of the rows. Initially we have:
$$                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                            
S = (4, 2, 3) \\                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                             
P = (2, 1, 3)                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                
$$
Swap rows $1$ and $2$ since row $2$ has the maximum pivot relative to its row:
$$                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                             
\begin{pmatrix}2&2&0\\                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                       
                -1&1&-4\\                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                    
                3& 3& 2\end{pmatrix}                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                         
\begin{pmatrix}x_1\\x_2\\x_3\end{pmatrix} =                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                  
\begin{pmatrix}1\\0\\\frac{1}{2}\end{pmatrix}                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                
$$
Now compute the following elementary row operations w.r.t. the ordering given by $p$:
\begin{align}                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                
  A^{(1)}_1 &= A^{(0)}_1 - \tfrac{-1}{2}A^{(0)}_2 \\                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                        
  A^{(1)}_3 &= A^{(0)}_3 - \tfrac{3}{2}A^{(0)}_2                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                            
\end{align}
This yields:
$$                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                           
\begin{pmatrix}2&2&0\\                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                       
               0&2&-4\\                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                      
               0&0&2\end{pmatrix}                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                            
\begin{pmatrix}x_1\\x_2\\x_3\end{pmatrix}=                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                   
\begin{pmatrix}1\\\frac{1}{2}\\-1                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                            
\end{pmatrix}                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                
$$
Now using back substitution to solve for $x$ we get:
$$                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                            
x=\begin{pmatrix}\frac{-1}{4}\\\frac{3}{4}\\\frac{-1}{2}\end{pmatrix}                                                                                                                                                                                                                                        
$$
Clearly, I must have made a mistake along the way since the solutions for both methods are not the same! I know that the scaled pivoting is incorrect as I checked my solution in a C.A.S. and it matched the solution for the Basic Method.

Please show me what I have done wrong in the scaled pivoting algorithm.

Comment: Check $x_2$ from your second back substitution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You miscomputed $x_2$ in the back substitution of the row-pivoted system, that's the origin of the discrepancy.

Comment: You are correct! and WooooW! What a waste of time typing all of that up. Well not a waste, just more TeX practice!

Comment: @CodeKingPlusPlus: Your expenses in efforts to accurately describe the problem have been my savings in efforts to find the error. In that sense, thanks, and anytime again.

Comment: If you are good with vector norms, check this question out: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/454411/proving-the-triangle-inequality-for-the-l-2-norm-x-2-sqrtx-12x-22-ld